# Restrict the Mule from picking file in SFTP

Tags: mule, sftp

How to restrict picking the empty file ie 0 kb text file through SFTP in Mule?

Answer (score 0):

you can extend the sftp connector functionality using the "sevice over rides" concept.

you can check the size of the file content before control comes to flow.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+a+Transport#ConfiguringaTransport-overrides

Answer (score 0):

Please look `sizeCheckWaitTime`,`fileAge` attributes.

I was facing use 0 byte issue. I resolved using above attributes.